# Turn off bluetooth in sleep mode windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, sleep

How can I achieve the simple following functionality:

1. When the laptop sleeps/hibernates -> bluetooth turns off
2. When the laptop wakes up -> bluetooth turns on

The reason for this, is that I have BT earphones that are connected to both my laptop and my phone, but on sleep mode, my laptop turns BT on and off every few minutes.
This disrupts my listening when connected to the phone.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found a solution to this. Been aggravating me for months.

The hint lies here in [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1639062/turn-off-bluetooth-automatically-if-unused-for-30-minutes). Bluetooth adapters are generally connected internally via USB. Now for the solution.

Open up control panel, go to Hardware and Sound then edit power settings.

[image: Control panel home screen]

[image: Edit power plan]

Next hit Change advanced power options.

[image: Advanced power settings]

Now expand USB Settings -> USB selective suspend setting

Set on battery to disabled.

[image: USB Settings -> USB selective suspend setting -> On battery: Disabled]

Now whenever your computer is asleep and on battery USB will be inactive, therefore disabling Bluetooth as well. Of course the downside is USB will also not work for anything else, although I don't know what else you'd be doing with it while asleep and on battery. You can also change the setting for plugged in.

Comment: any suggestions if I don't see "USB settings" in the power plan?

Comment: @Danyal not sure but I see [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/usb-settings-in-power-plan-options-on-windows-10/38753b89-65d0-49c1-8f91-2bb50f9b19a0). Probably worth a look anyway.