# Turn off Bluetooth automatically if unused for 30 minutes

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth

On Windows 10, is there a way to automatically turn off Bluetooth if it is idle for more than 30 minutes?

Comment: Find out what it is part of. Normally wireless. Airplane Mode will normally turn both wireless and bluetooth off. So if part of wireless, you will only want it off if you want wireless off. Otherwise it will be on. Wireless can be turned off in power properties in Windows.

Comment: I can manually turn off bluetooth without turning off wireless from the action centre.

Comment: Check in Device Manager. There is no power option for Bluetooth in either of my laptops.  But yes, you can turn it off manually. It also needs to be on to make it discoverable.

Comment: I don't see any power options for bluetooth (nor for the wireless adapter). However, could one write a script to accomplish this?

Comment: You would need to look in Stack Overflow for such a script.  Here is a Powershell script:  https://superuser.com/questions/1168551/turn-on-off-bluetooth-radio-adapter-from-cmd-powershell-in-windows-10

Comment: Thanks, that seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

On laptops Bluetooth is connected to the USB ports, just inside the computer rather than external.

In Device Manager you can set sleep and wake options for USB. But with no way of telling what the device is, so if you want to make your options global to all USB devices see Device Manager.